# type 'Future<List<Iterable<Book>>>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<List<Book>>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

im getting that error , can you help?

```dart
class BooksViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  Database _database = Database();

  Stream<List<Book>> getBookList() {
    const String booksRef = "books";

    ///stream<QuerySnapshot> --> Stream<List><DocumentSnapshot>>
    Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> streamListDocument = _database
        .getBookListFromApi(booksRef)
        .map((querySnapshot) => querySnapshot.docs);

    /// Stream<List><DocumentSnapshot> --> Stream<List><Book>

    Stream<List<Book>> streamListBook = streamListDocument
        .map((listOfDocSnap) => listOfDocSnap.map(
            (docSnap) => Book.fromMap(docSnap.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)))
        .toList() as Stream<List<Book>>;

    return streamListBook;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to call `.toList()` after the inner `.map` rather than the outer `.map`. The following code just moves the closing paren to after the `.toList()`:

```dart
Stream<List<Book>> streamListBook = streamListDocument
    .map((listOfDocSnap) => listOfDocSnap.map(
        (docSnap) => Book.fromMap(docSnap.data() as Map<String, dynamic>))
    .toList()) as Stream<List<Book>>;
```